# how to avoid empty first page on jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a jasper report with two pages. There is a page brake in the ireport design. When I put many elements on the second page of the report the report, it starts to generate the first page empty and then generates the first page as the second, and the second page as the third. So the problem is that the first empty page should not be rendered. This happens only when I put a certain number of elements on the second page after the page break.

My jrxml:

the xml was to big to paste it here so I'm giving the link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw2gLXmFOkbWSHdXYm8tVjJycXM/view?usp=sharing

and here is the example generated output:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw2gLXmFOkbWSEJudXU1a1hZNGs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Having a quick view at your report I have seen that you have but almost everyting in the detail band, consider using groups then you can set paramaters as minHeightToStartNewPage and splitType.

Comment: @Petter Friberg tnx for the idea, I have choosen the option to create three templates and cobine them in one document at the end. My report is not so sequential. I was also a little bit surprised that there is a problem with the height of detail band, I would expect it to be as high as neaded and that then the reprt engine brakes the report in pages on compile time.

Comment: I guess the report engine, does the best it can.... Consider posting your solution as answer and accept it to help others.